# R - print value of a data frame using a function brings NULL value

Tags: r

I have a data frame called outcome1 with only one column called "pneumonia" using

```
outcome1 <- data.frame(Pneumonia = sample(0:1, size = 5, replace = TRUE))
```

I create a function called best1 that just prints that column using an argument called "var_"

```
best1 <- function(var_) {
  outcome1$var_
}
```

when I call the function

```
 best1("Pneumonia")
```

I get a NULL value

but when I use:

```
outcome1$Pneumonia
```

I get the data I need.  How can I use the best1 function and get the right results using the column name as an argument, also what would be the case if the column would have a space in the name I know that you use the "``" in that case, what would be the case in using it in a function, thanks for the help

Comment: Don't use `$` use `[[`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a better way to write your function.

```
best1 <- function(var_) {
  outcome1[[var_]]
}
```

See `?$` for valid inputs for using that operator. Your function is looking for the variable name "var_", not the string bound to that name.

Comment: Thanks that solved the issue :)